# What does this reply imply after a missed application deadline?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, email, canada

I missed the deadline to apply for admission in PhD programs of the University of Toronto by a month (because of my job restrictions!). So I mailed the University's PG office asking whether there can be any extension to which they replied:

> Hello,
> Unfortunately, we are no longer
> accepting new MASc/PhD applications
> unless a faculty member reaches out
> to us directly requesting to open a
> new application specifically for
> you.
> Best Regards,

So how should I proceed now? Should I mail the potential supervisors now? If yes then should I attach the other documents too (Resume, transcripts, Statement of Intent, Proposal)?

Answer (score 22):

It means they aren't taking applications any more, you missed the deadline. "Job restrictions", whatever that means, is not an excuse for missing a deadline.

They are saying that in special cases you can work around the deadline, but that's not the normal order of things. An example of how this might work would be that an undergraduate is working in the lab and about to graduate. The professor and student have a conversation and discover that the student would like to do a PhD in that lab and the professor likes their work and wants them to stay on. This is past the ordinary application deadline, but if the professor wants to commit the funds the department is willing to review whether they'd admit them despite the missed deadline.

This is not the same as "the application deadline is just a suggestion, and you can apply past the deadline if you contact professors directly".

If you don't already know specific people there that know you and would work to make an exception for you, I don't think this is intended as an invitation to reach out to professors cold. There's probably no cost except your time to do so, but I would not expect it to be fruitful. Be more aware of deadlines in the future.

Comment: Oh I thought that a potential supervisor might be able to open the application in case I manage to engage him/ her with good enough credentials and or a proposal.

Comment: @Candy It's not impossible, but that's not how it's supposed to work. You're supposed to apply by the deadline.

Comment: And should the advisors be contacted before applying?

Comment: @Candy Look to the department/graduate program website for guidance on that. My understanding is that usually in Canada no, you apply to the department first, though I would certainly reach out if your whole purpose to applying for a program is to work with a specific professor; if they're not taking students, then you have no reason to apply there.

Comment: @Candy Your credentials must be *really* good to convince a supervisor now, not just good enough. They already have tons of applicants who are good enough *and also punctual*; the latter is also an important skill.

Answer (score 5):

You're too late. The deadline is over. They could potentially make an exception if a faculty member requests an exception, but it's improbable they will, especially if they don't know you (you *are* too late; the default reaction will be to say no). Besides, even if they say yes, you are likely to be too late. Even if you can fill up all the application forms and do all the required tests in a day, you almost surely need to get reference letters as well, which will add even more processing time.

So how should you proceed now? Options:

1. Write to your prospective supervisor and convince them to request an exception for you. It's very likely to result in "no", but you could ask.
2. Apply somewhere else, where it's not yet the application deadline. There are also universities with no deadlines, you can start at any time ([example](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137132/i-missed-the-phd-application-deadline-what-now)).
3. Wait a year and try again.

Comment: I would suggest waiting *less* than a year, lest it happens again :)